# Soma automática de dois EditText para colocar resultado em um TextView

Tags: java, android

Quero pegar dois valores de dois `EditText` e colocar o resultado desses dois valores em um `TextView`. Fiz esse código mas esta dando esse erro

```
editPecaBoas = findViewById(R.id.editPecaBoas);

editPecaRuins = findViewById(R.id.editPecaRuins);


public void sumParts() {

    TextWatcher watcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            int a = Integer.parseInt(editPecaBoas.getText().toString());
            int b = Integer.parseInt(editPecaRuins.getText().toString());

            int i = a + b;

            String t = String.valueOf(i);

            textViewResult.setText(t);
        }
    };
```

O erro é esse

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O erro mencionado ocorre por que você está tentando converter uma `String` vazia em um `int`, você pode adicionar uma validação, para caso o um dos `EditText` estiver vazio considerar o valor `0`. 
Exemplo:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

    String valueStrEditPecaBoas = editPecaBoas.getText().toString();
    String valueStrEditPecaRuins = editPecaRuins.getText().toString();

    int pecasBoas, pecasRuins;

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(valueStrEditPecaBoas)) {
        pecasBoas = 0;
        editPecaBoas.setText("0");
    } else {
        pecasBoas = Integer.parseInt(valueStrEditPecaBoas);
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(valueStrEditPecaRuins)) {
        pecasRuins = 0;
        editPecaRuins.setText("0");
    } else {
        pecasRuins = Integer.parseInt(valueStrEditPecaRuins);
    }

    textViewResult.setText(String.valueOf(pecasBoas + pecasRuins));
}
```

Nesse exemplo também fiz um `setText("0")` para ter um retorno visual no campo, mas ele não é necessário para resolver o seu erro.